# jQuery .find() inputs of multiple types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following jQuery to clone a set of input fields (1 Select field, 2 Text fields and 1 Number field)

```
$("#add_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".form-row :first").clone().insertAfter(".form-row :last").find("input[type='text']").val("");
});
```

Is there any way I can extend this so the cloned number fields don't also contain the values.

I've tried

```
$("#add_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".form-row :first").clone().insertAfter(".form-row :last").find("input[type='text|number']").val("");
});
```

Which doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector in `.find("input[type='text|number']")` is incorrect. To select multiple elements, separate the selectors by comma.

```
.find("input[type='text'], input[type='number']")
```

See [Multiple Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

---

To set empty string as value to all the `input` elements, use element selector.

```
.find('input').val('')
```

Comment: Thanks, I guessed the `|` was an invalid seperator, just didn't occur to me to use two selectors with a `,` seperator

Answer (score 0):

You must use a multiple element selector using `,` to separate each selector; like:

```
$("#add_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".form-row :first").clone().insertAfter(".form-row :last").find("input[type='text'], input[type='number']").val("");
});
```